# require(): Failed opening required 'E:\xampp\htdocs\complete-php7-ecom-website-master\vendor\autoload.php' (include_path='E:\xampp\php\PEAR

Tags: javascript, java, php, wordpress, xampp

Warning: require(E:\xampp\htdocs\complete-php7-ecom-website-master\vendor\autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in E:\xampp\htdocs\complete-php7-ecom-website-master\config\bootstrap.php on line 34

Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required 'E:\xampp\htdocs\complete-php7-ecom-website-master\vendor\autoload.php' (include_path='E:\xampp\php\PEAR') in E:\xampp\htdocs\complete-php7-ecom-website-master\config\bootstrap.php on line 34

this error over  E:\xampp\htdocs\complete-php7-ecom-website-master\config\bootstrap.php on line 34

require VENDOR . 'autoload.php';

Comment: What are you trying to do and what code do you have? It's very hard to help with just the error message.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.